# getting pdf data out of pdf context

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgcontext

I'm very new to the world of contexts.

1. I create a pdfcontext using:

   ```
   NSMutableData* pdfData = [ [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:1000] retain];
   CGRect bounds = (CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));
   NSDictionary* documentInfo = nil;
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData (pdfData,
                                bounds,
                                documentInfo);
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
   ```
2. Then I draw to it with different classes
3. Then I issue

   ```
   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
   ```

when I'm done drawing to it.

What I'm not clear on is how do I get the pdfData out of the context so I can send it back to my caller as NSData. Any help appreciated. I'm assuming in my approach that the pdfData gets retained within the context. 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you need to do with the pdfData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext`, it puts the PDF data into the `pdfData` object that you provided.  Since an `NSMutableData` is a subclass of `NSData`, you can just return it to your caller.  There is no need to do anything else.

Also, don't do this:

```
NSMutableData* pdfData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:1000] retain];
```

alloc/init returns a retained object. There is no need to retain it again. Also, there's no need to specify a size for the data -- it will get expanded automatically.  So just do this:

```
NSMutableData* pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

Comment: you the man. thank you Kurt. now I get the NSData back from to context. woohoo. any tips on which direction to go to actually create a pdf file from this data in a separate method ?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000717-149198).